# Does (1-a)^n converge when n grows?

Tags: limits

Just wondering where the expression

$(1-a)^n$
goes when $n$ goes to infinity.

Comment: This depends on the value of $a$.

Comment: Try $a=2$. Try different numbers in your calculator.

Comment: @Josué, being a member for three years, you should know by now to not post questions without context.

Answer (score 2):

The answer depends on $a$. For $(1-a)^{n}$ to converge as $n \to \infty$, we must have $|1-a| < 1$ or $1-a = 1$. So it converges for $a \in [0, 2)$.

Comment: Don't you mean $a \in (0, 2)$?

Comment: Corrected, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

For $b \in \mathbb R$, the sequence $b^n$ converges iff $|b|<1$ or $b=1$.
In the first case, the limit is $0$. In the second case, the limit is $1$.

Now apply this result to $b=1-a$.